# my ncurses noecho() doesn't work

Tags: ncurses

For some reason my `noecho()` initialization is not working, until I give an input twice. The first time I press `h`, I get an `'h'` char on the screen. However, next pressed keys don't appear on the screen. How can I prevent ALL input from showing?

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main(){
    initscr();                      /* Start curses mode */        
    raw();                          /* prevents use of signals from ctl + c
    noecho();                       /* suppress echo */

    mvprintw(10,10,"Hello World!!");        /* Print */
    refresh();                      /* print it on real screen */

    while(true){
            char ch = getch();              /* wait for input */
            if(ch == 'q')
                    break;
            else if(ch == 'h'){
                    mvprintw(10,10,"Test");
            }
            else{
                    attroff(A_BOLD);
            }
    }

    endwin();                       /* end curses mode */
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment is un-ended, making the compiler ignore `noecho`:

```
raw();                          /* prevents use of signals from ctl + c
noecho();                       /* suppress echo */
```

You can see this if you use gcc's warnings:

```
foo.c:3:5: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
foo.c: In function ‘main’:
foo.c:6:37: warning: "/*" within comment [-Wcomment]
foo.c:12:23: warning: conversion to ‘char’ from ‘int’ may alter its value [-Wconversion]
```